# Use assemby reference like an Project reference in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, reference

I have a C# project with some referenced dll's. To inspect the whole Project it would be nice to replace the referenced dll's against the existing project references temporarily.

The benefits were "the search in the whole solution" and "Go to Definition" makes more sense.

Is there a trick to replace references in the *.csproj file?
Or is there a Visual Studio extension to achieve the benefits?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to remove the reference and add it again as a project reference from Visual Studio?- (You also have to add the project to the solution)

Comment: The drawback of your suggestion is that it would affect the repository of source safe. It would be nice if there is a smarter solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with ReSharper.
You can open and disassemble the references with the extension ReSharper and set break points.